# Limit of Quotient with a Square root with Odd Power

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been studying limits for some time now, and I've stumbled into a bit of a problem. Yes, I am a new student.

So, for example, with the function

$f(x) = \sqrt{x^3 + 1}/x^5$

If I want to see the limit as in it reaches infinity, would it go:

1. $\lim_{x\to ∞} \sqrt{x^3 + 1}/x^5$

   $\lim_{x\to ∞} x\sqrt{x+1/x^2}/ x^5$

   $\lim_{x\to ∞} \sqrt{x+1/x^2}/ x^4$

OR

2. $\lim_{x\to ∞} \sqrt{x^3 + 1}/x^5$

   $\lim_{x\to ∞} x^2\sqrt{1/x+1/x^4}/ x^5$

   $\lim_{x\to ∞} \sqrt{1/x+1/x^4}/ x^3$

I've tried asking my teacher about it, but still can't understand well. Thanks to those answering.

Comment: If $x>\sqrt 2$ then $0<\sqrt {x^3+1}\,/x^5<\sqrt {2x^3}\,/x^5=\sqrt 2\,/x^{7/2}<1/x^3<1/x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is correct.  In No 1. however, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ and only because $x\to\infty$ you may drop the absolute value so that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$.  To actually determine the limit, it might be better to

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^3 + 1}}{x^5}
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{3/2}\sqrt{1+1/x^3}}{x^5} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+1/x^3}\to1}{x^{7/2}\to\infty} \\
\end{align}$$

This because in 1. you get $\infty/\infty$.

Comment: I thought $x^(7/2)$ increases to infinity, since 7 > 2.

Comment: Of course, yes. Fixed.